# How to find key from the value given in a dictionary in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am creating a project where I am stuck to a concept of retrieving key from given value. 
I have created a tableview  adding the dictionary values- say "city_names" for key "city_id".
If user selects a city then I want to get the respective "city_id" for that city.

I have dictionary in the form

```
"city":[
    {
        "id":"1",
        "city":"City1"
    },
    {
        "id":"2",
        "city":"City2"
    },
    {
        "id":"3",
        "city":"musat"
    },
    {
        "id":"4",
        "city":"city3"
    },
    {
        "id":"5",
        "city":"City 4"
    }
]
```

I am rather concerned about getting corresponding index of the child dictionary of which the city is selected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure you have ever read this docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html but it is never too late to take a look on `–allKeysForObject:` method.

Comment: This is not a Dictionary, this is array of Dictionary if you look at the "[ ]" part it indicates that it is an Array... and its "{}" its dictionary.... @vin

Comment: yes I know it. kamarshad. But what i really want is to display the "city_name" that i implemented by getting another array.
but I am unable to get corresponding "city_id" from the array of dictionary when user selects a particular row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So presumably you are populating the tableview, via its datasource methods, and want to reference back to your model data when the user selects a particular row?

In that case you should probably be keeping an array of keys as well as the model dictionary. You can then retrieve the key from the key-array using the row passed into the tableview delegate and from there get the key to the dictionary entry.

This works because an array has a fixed order, as does a tableview, and you have the advantage of sorting the array in whatever order suits the data being displayed.  Dictionaries do not have a fixed order and so should not be used as the sole container for model data.

The downside to this approach is that you need to maintain two data structures, and therefore the best approach is to create a custom class for your model data, and use a single array of these model objects.  There are many more advantages to this approach.

Comment: It is difficult to maintain the data structures like arrays or classes of names and ids. Cause more results may to the array in further scope of the project. Most of them are null characters of city_names. I am eliminating those null city_names while displaying to the user. Its difficult to get its corresponding city_id by this method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
   int index = [[city valueForKey:@"city"] indexOfObject:@"Selected_City"];
NSString *selected_id = [[city valueForKey:@"id"] objectAtIndex:index];
```

Answer (score 0):

On based of your description.

I will suggest you make your data in form of `Array(NSarray)` of `Dictionaries`.
And as populate your `UITableViewCell` according to this `array`.

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method

```
Dictionaries* dict = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString * selectedCityId = [dict objectForKey:@"passYourKeyIdentifier"];
```